Planar Turing Machine with (relatively) Small Alphabet
There is a simple construction that takes any drawing of a Turing Machine in the plane and outputs another planar, equivalent one with a "small" blowup in the number of states, and only two more symbols. Specifically, if there are $s$ transition crossings (originally), then it is straightforward to add $3s$ states (and quadratically many transitions in the tape alphabet size) to make the diagram planar. Moreover, the tape alphabet size has exactly 2 more characters than the starting alphabet.
Thus if there are $q$ states and $s$ tape symbols in a TM $M$, then there is an equivalent planar TM $M'$ to $M$ with $O(q^2)$ states and $s+2$ tape symbols, as there are at most $O(q^2)$ arrows since transitions can be grouped.
My question: is there an improvement that can be made on this? I am not able to find any reference on such a conversion.
